# Disable Text Input Google App Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I'm a new user to Google App Script and I'm trying to disable a text input using Google App Script in the HTML file. I've tried:

```
      $('#company-name').attr('enabled', false);
```

and I've also tried

```
      $('#company-name').enabled = false;
```

This is within a script section on the HTML page. The function with these lines of code is called when prepopulating a form. However, the text box can still be edited after the form is prepopulated.

How do I edit form element attributes and disable a text box or other input?

Comment: This is not an Apps Script question.  It's an HTML question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "enabled" attribute.  There is only a `disabled` attribute:

```
$("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

OR:

```
$('#company-name').attr('disabled', true);
```